# Working with potential null arguements in TypeScript argument signature

Tags: typescript

In my application I have a service that has methods that are used many times. A method takes a series of arguments like so (the name / indication of the arguments is irrelevant in my example)....

```
doSomething(url: string, data: any, qParams?: QueryParams) {}
```

Now I need to extend this to take a forth optional argument like so:

```
doSomething(url: string, data: any, qParams?: QueryParams, headers?: HeadersType) {}
```

Please note that `QueryParams` and `HeadersType` are two custom types I have written. However there will be cases when `qParams` will be null and headers will contain a `headersType` object. Thus in some cases I will call the method like so `doSomething(urlValue, dataVal)` or `doSomething(urlVal, dataVal, qParamsVal)` or `doSomething(urlVal, dataVal, null, headersVal)` or `doSomething(urlVal, dataVal, qParamsVal, headersVal)`

What is the best way to prevent having to put a null value into the argument list when I want to have the `headersVal` but not a `qParamsVal`. I realise I could just pass an object with keys, but can I use a spread operator or something else. I am using TypeScript and my App is written using Angular2.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you have 4 arguments, it might make sense to pass them as an object with 4 properties, some of them optional.

You can use [shorthand object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) when calling, and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the arguments when defining the method, so the various ways to call the  method will look like

```
doSomething({url, data})  // when actual parameters names match args names exactly 

doSomething({url: urlVal, data: dataVal}); // when they don't

doSomething({url: urlVal, data: dataVal, qParams: qParamsVal});

doSomething({url: urlVal, data: dataVal, headers: headersVal}); 

doSomething({url, data, qParams, headers: headersVal});
```

You will have to define an interface for the parameter, so there will be some name repetition when you define a function:

```
interface DoSomething {
    url: string;
    data: any; 
    qParams?: QueryParams;
    headers?: HeadersType;
}
doSomething({url, data, qParams, headers}: DoSomething): void {
    .... 
    if (qParams) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The advantage is that parameters are always named, and you don't have to remember exact order and how many nulls to insert for optional arguments when calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that QueryParams and HeadersType are two custom types I have written. [...] What is the best way to prevent having to put a null value into the argument list when I want to have the headersVal but not a qParamsVal

In this case, it might be feasible to create additional [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for `doSomething`. It will complicate the method definition a little, but will yield a clean call signature:

```
// Callable signatures:
doSomething(url: string, data: any, qParams?: QueryParams);
doSomething(url: string, data: any, headers?: HeadersType);
doSomething(url: string, data: any, qParams?: QueryParams, headers?: HeadersType);

// Method implementation:
doSomething(url: string, data: any, qParamsOrHeaders?: QueryParams | HeadersType, headers?: HeadersType) {
    // The function body should determine which overload signature was used:
    if (qParamsOrHeaders instanceof QueryParams && headers instanceof HeadersType) {
        // used signature: (string, any, QueryParams, HeadersType)
        // ...
    } else if (qParamsOrHeaders instanceof HeadersType) {
        // used signature: (string, any, HeadersType)
        // ...
    } else if (qParamsOrHeaders instanceof QueryParams) {
        // used signature: (string, any, QueryParams)
        // ...
    } else {
        // used signature: (string, any)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, this requires that `QueryParams` and `HeadersType` are actual class types.